# Google Chrome how can i allow this to work? i am unable to make it work

Tags: google-chrome, https

My cloud application is programmed already.

Which gets loaded using `https://example.com` to Google Chrome, then Google Chrome is accessing to the local machine as `https://192.168.1.27/`

but for security Google Chrome fails because the certificates are self-certified inside the embedded box of 192.168.1.27 (which i cant change).

But i trust it my lan and this device 100%. How can i instruct Google Chrome to avoid this and allow straight access?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)

Comment: @this.lau_: i applied http://stackoverflow.com/a/17321045/285594 , but its very very very slow browser when this is applied: --ignore-certificate-errors

Answer (score 0):

You cant as of Google Chrome stable version (13 May 2015)

Ask Chrome Team to fix it. Its not logical and should be treated as BUG. When a programmer trust his lan and his own robots. There is no logic involved Google chrome should still un-trust it (so Chrome Team should brain storm it and add the feature).